# Sencha Touch 2 getting an element focused after it renders

Tags: extjs, view

I want something like jquery onReady function in sencha view/component. I wand to get an element (textarea) focused when it gets rendered in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a listener for `initialize`:

```
{
    xtype: 'textareafield',
    listeners: {
        initialize: function(ta) {
            ta.focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use 
order : 'after',
painted : function() {}

please see this:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?244088-Is-there-a-afterrender-afterlayout-event

Hope it can help.